# Не перейти к диску в консоли через SSH соединение

Tags: ssh, криптография, ssl

Использую Kitty для подключения и какая-та она багованная. Например она не может в кодировку и из-за этого я вижу лишь иероглифы. Вместо синего окна, я вижу черный, а где текст - синий. С помощью команды cd не могу попасть в диск D или я просто не указал что его можно использовать? Я так понимаю это шифрованное соединение с помощью SSl?

Comment: Дык, смените кодировку в настройках, если не ошибаюсь "Window -> Translation". В чём вопрос-то? Сам я, например, использую xshell .

Comment: Подождите, вы по SSH зашли на машину с Windows, что там есть диск `D`?

Comment: @D-side да, именно так

Comment: А что за SSH-сервер у вас там используется? Так, из праздного любопытства.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к вопросу про SSH-сервер. Потому что, сейчас, впервые услышав про эту Kitty, скачал ее, и с дефолтными настройками подключился к домашнему компьютеру. Никаких описанных в вопросе проблем не обнаружилось.

Comment: @D-side freesshd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я полагаю, `freesshd` делает вам удалённую сессию в `cmd`.
В нём `cd` не переходит на другие диски.

Для перехода по некоему пути в томе `D` (например), будучи на томе `C` (например) достаточно просто ввести полный путь, например просто **`D:`**. Безо всяких `cd` и прочего.

---

*Об иероглифах и испорченных цветах можно только гадать в сторону кодировки и совместимости вашего SSH-клиента и среды, в которой он работает. Или сервера, хотя в этом я сомневаюсь. Выяснить, виноват ли сервер, можно, зайдя другим SSH-клиентом, можно даже с другой ОС, для гарантии.*